# Wildcard redirect in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do something rather easy - seemingly.

I would like to redirect everything after a section of the url like mydomain.com/somepart/x/y/z  to another particular section.

So far I have the following:

```
Route::get('/somepart/{any}', function () {

    return redirect('/somepart2/*');

});
```

but this is not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Route::get('/somepart/{any}', function ($any) {
    return redirect('/somepart2/'.$any);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/routing-with-dynamic-number-of-params-in-laravel-5):

Try this:

```
Route::get('somepart/{foo}/', 'YourController@method')->where('foo','.+');
```